# change the form fields using dropdown select in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-dependencies, setstate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

[Change the form field by selecting different fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeLIO.gif)qVS3e.gif

Comment: Please elaborate your question to be more clear and specific, you just provided 2 links and only one of them is working and provide some sort of code for better understanding and problem solving matter. I have tried to provide the answer for the question bellow.

Comment: i will try that i am posting question first time so it not to undestandable thank you for the help

Comment: how can i implement it on flutter

Answer (score -1):

Try to use some kind of switch case or any form of iterator, when selecting the item from the drop down menu, you pass the value to another switch case again (or if statements, what ever you prefer) that renders the input fields depending on the selected value from the dropdown menu.

```
enum Menu { one, two, three }
PopupMenuButton<Menu>(
                                    onSelected: (methods) {
                                      switch (methods) {
                                        case Menu.one:
                                          /// method that passed the data and tells some sort of builder like an `ListView` Builder, hey build a list with these form fields
                                          break;
                                        case Menu.two:
                                          // another method with different form fields
                                          break;
                                        case Menu.three:
                                          // and again, a different method
                                          break;
                                      }
                                    },
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                        <PopupMenuEntry<Menu>>[
                                      const PopupMenuItem<Menu>(
                                        value: Menu.one,
                                        child: Text('One'),
                                      ),
                                      const PopupMenuItem<Menu>(
                                        value: Menu.two,
                                        child: Text('Two'),
                                      ),
                                      const PopupMenuItem<Menu>(
                                        value: Menu.three,
                                        child: Text('Three'),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
```

then the passed value from the `PopUpMenu` is put in a, like I said, switch case like above or an if statement:

```
if(value from dropdown one){
// build a `Form` with specific `TextFormField`s
} else if (value from the dropdown two) {
   // build this `Form` with specific `TextFormField`s
} else (value from dropdown three){
// then build this `Form` with specific `TextFormField`s
}
```